# Cant change callerid option

Tags: caller-id, oneplus, android-13

I'm not sure if this is the right place, but using oneplus official forums didn't give any answers.

I changed my callerid to anonymous a few months ago, and i can't change it back to showing my callerId.

All guids and FAQ's show me where to find the option and change it, but the callerid button in my phone is disabled/grayed out.

I have no idea why, tried restarting the phone, disable/enable sim card, and fiddling with settings without any luck.

Has anyone here encountered anythin similar, and know how to fix this ?

[image]

My device is oneplus 10 pro
running android version 13.

Comment: Are you sure it still hides your number when calling? Because it should have been reverted to show caller id before disabling. Is it a stock Phone App?

Comment: It still hides my number, friends and family have commented on it, when i'm calling them. 
The screenshot is from the settings app, not a 3rd party app.